# How to "import" a controller.js file in the angular.module file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting to learn Angular so the issue I'm trying to figure out here might be a bit awkwardly formulated. I'll try my best and explain what I'm dealig with.

I have a main main.js module file where I have declared

```
angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute'
```

])

Now I have a separrate file for the controller as home.controller.js which contains

```
angular
.module('app')    
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]);
```

Is there any way to include the home.controller.js file withing the main.js file without having to put the script src in the html ? I have tried to `import 'path/home.conntroller.js` but I get this error

*Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.*

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure main.js is included in your HTML file before home.controller.js ... for example:

```html
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="home.controller.js"></script>
```